# Save different data for same user on different Guilds

Tags: discord, discord.net

I set up a `stats` command as follows

```
[Command("Stats")]
        public async Task StatsOther(SocketUser socketUser = null)
        {
            if (socketUser == null)
            {
                socketUser = Context.User;
            }
            var account = UserAccounts.GetAccount(socketUser);
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Hey {socketUser.Mention}, You have {account.Size} long sandwhiches and {account.XP} XP.");
        }
```

And the class `UserAccounts` searches if there exists in our database a `socketUser` with the `ID` property. Now say the same user in on different guild I need to store different data for him but the `socketUser.ID` will be the same no matter the guild. So when the user tries to use `stats` command he will see the same data irrespective of the guild he is in right now.

Here is where `UserAccounts.GetAccount` leads and does its thing,

```
public static UserAccount GetAccountFromID(ulong ID)
        {
            var result = from a in accounts
                         where a.ID == ID
                         select a;

            var FoundAccount = result.FirstOrDefault();
            if (FoundAccount == null)
            {
                FoundAccount = CreateUserAccount(ID);
            }
            return FoundAccount;
        }
```

Clearly the linq query is checking for IDs and they happen to be the same for a user no matter the guild.

I tried using `SocketGuildUser` but sadly a `socketGuildUser.ID` is also independent of the guild. So I am unable to store different data for the same user from different guilds. Using the latest beta available.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implemented for each user. Where each user have its own `Dictionary<GuildID, Data>`.

And on the SQL side (if you are using SQL), you could have a new table, where it has a foreign key constrain on the User ID, and has a Guild ID too.
(The foreign key constrain on userID might not be needed if none of the user's stats is shared between all guilds; Aka you just have a SQL-table which you can do a `SELECT stuff FROM tableName WHERE userID = ? AND guildID = ?`)

Comment: After a lot of effort as i use json this finally worked. Thanks.